# Multiple Galleries in WordPress 3.3.1

Tags: gallery

There are a good plugin, that allows user to make several galleries in one post not using manually "include" attribute.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-galleries/

But after upgrading on 3.3.1 core version of WordPress this plugin don't work anymore. (I suggest this is because of changes in file post manager.)

Does anybody know the way to fix that? Maybe there is another plugin that realize this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Nextgen](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) and problem solved. You can add as many galleries as you want. And you're right, sadly, this core upgrade killed a lot of amazing plugins. I have downgraded sites because of that.

Comment: Fabio, when referencing plugins, it's best to place a link to said plugin for the convenience of the reader. :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has already been answered, I shall expose my solution to a common problem, relating to using one or more galleries in one page.

One of the page templates of my client's website has 2 galleries, that are different, but that will always be present on such a page of that aforementioned type. So she needs a simple way to upload pictures to one or the other. Multiple images per gallery.

So I used the [Verve Meta-boxes plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes), and created a box for each gallery. There, for each image in one gallery I have a text and and image field.

All I have to do now is read the right fields on the front office. Voilá.

Hope it helps.